# How to make the first commit on WordPress.org

Tags: plugin-development, wordpress.org

I've created a plugin and I've uploaded it to WordPress.org, but I see the message "This plugin is approved and awaiting data upload but not visible to the public yet. Once you make your first commit, the plugin will become public."

Here is the [plugin link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/haq-testimonial). How can I get rid of this message?

Comment: You have to read [How to Use Subversion](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/).

Comment: I have read many times of this instruction and follow step by step but not able to make first commit.

Comment: Did you get any error message while following the steps?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following steps to make first commit in wordpress.org

- Please install SVN in your System.
- Make a folder in your computer so that you can upload Plugin content from this folder to WordPress Repository. (i.e. plugin folder in d: drive)
- But please do not use your this folder localhost/example/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-name.
- Please check your mail for SVN repository Link.
- So you have installed SVN then, right click on folder you created and click SVN Checkout.
- Please add URL of repository from you mail and checkout directory and Leave other setting as it is and click OK.
- After that open folder you created (i.e. Plugin) you will see the changes in it.
- The latest code for plugin lies on trunk.
- After copying our files we need to commit our SVN folder.
- Right Click on your plugin folder and click SVN commit and box pops out and add message in “Recent messages”.
- Leave rest field as default and click OK.
- Now you can see your plugin in WordPress Repository.
- If you have any confusion then you also can follow the following blog :
  [Upload Plugin in WordPress.org with SVN](http://merobox.com/upload-plugin-in-wordpress-org-repository/)